# Trouble with layer.shadowColor and UIColors

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

Trying to change the color of a shadow. This works:

```
self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
```

[image]

but i want to make it a custom color, so i tried:

```
self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:191/255.0f green:199/255.0f blue:203/255.0f alpha:1] CGColor];
```

[image]

which does not work.

what am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

code snippet from my init method:

```
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
//self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:191/255.0f green:199/255.0f blue:203/255.0f alpha:1] CGColor];
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 4;
```

EDIT 2:

odd part is that i extended UIColor to include some of my custom colors; if i use:

```
self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor pointColorBlue] CGColor];
```

from my UIColor+myColor:

```
+(UIColor *) pointColorBlue
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:50/255.0f green:50/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1];
}
```

it works fine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Works for me - what's the value of your `shadowOpacity` and `shadowOffset` on that view? What color is it displayed against? (The color you specify there is fairly light.)

Comment: question updated. when i try the RGB value, i do not get any shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah! figured it out: the graphics guy gave me that RGB value which is nearly identical to the background color!

Answer (score 0):

Those should work.

But you have to do following:

```
CALayer newLayer = [CALayer layer];
newLayer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];

self.layer = newLayer;
[self.layer setWantsLayer:YES];
```

It's important to reset the main layer, cause otherways it does not get drawn.

Comment: self.layer is read-only property, can't assign a layer to it.