# Removing shadow from subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiview, layer, subview, shadow

I have a UIView mainView, I've added 4 buttons in each corners as subviews. I added shadow to my mainView like this

```
mainView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
mainView.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,6);
mainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
```

My problem is that subviews show shadows (the buttons) too. How to hide subviews shadows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is peculiar. Have you tried to 'set' shadows on the subviews manually?

Comment: yes I tried, I doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: what is mainview? How did you get view property for UIVIEw ?@Vervatovskis

Comment: You can look for alternate solution. Something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358851/trouble-with-layer-shadowcolor-and-uicolors

Answer (score 1):

I have also fetch the same problem and found the solution of this issue.

- just set the background color for super view (Replace super view's background clear to any other color.)

EX: In above Questions

`mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`